# How to send the current form tab in a request.POST via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a form, in the form I have a series of objects, for each object there is a tab. For example:

`object 1: tab1`
`object 2: tab2`
`object 3: tab3`

Code example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="evidence-formset-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="evidence-form-1-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#evidence-form-1" role="tab" aria-controls="evidence-form-1" aria-selected="true">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="evidence-form-2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#evidence-form-2" role="tab" aria-controls="evidence-form-2" aria-selected="false">2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to know the value of the selected tab at the time of submitting the form.

JavaScript part:

```
function validateRegister() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#evidence-formset').attr('action', "{% url 'interpretation' %}").submit();
}
```

Is there a way to inject the value of the current tab and then process it in the (request.POST) in the backend?

Comment: You need to get `1` or `2` based on selected tabs ?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(".nav-item.active a").text()` to get value of active tab and then put this value inside input tag and append it to your form so that this will also get submitted.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function validateRegister() {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log($(".nav-item.active a").text())
  //get class which is active text() and append inside form..
  $('#evidence-formset').append("<input type='text' name='obj' value='" + $(".nav-item.active a").text() + "'>")
  $('#evidence-formset').attr('action', "{% url 'interpretation' %}").submit();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="evidence-formset-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="evidence-form-1-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#evidence-form-1" role="tab" aria-controls="evidence-form-1" aria-selected="true">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="evidence-form-2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#evidence-form-2" role="tab" aria-controls="evidence-form-2" aria-selected="false">2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="evidence-form-1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="evidence-form-2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
  </div>

</div>

<form id="evidence-formset">
  <button type="submit" onclick="validateRegister()">Click me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, looking good, for some reason on my end the `console.log($(".nav-item.active a").text())` has no value. It's always empty. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: which version of boostrap are you using ?

Comment: Currently I am using Bootstrap 4

Comment: That version adds active class to `a` tag so use `$(".nav-link.active").text()`

Comment: That was it! How did you know it was a version issue? Thank you very much

Comment: I am not sure how ,, but that first came to my mind when you said value not showing :) .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using [Bootstrap navs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/). If this is correct, you should mention it first (and tag your qeustion as such).

You can add a `<input type="hidden" name="activetab" id="activetab">` tag somewhere inside your `<form></form>`. Then add an event listener that updates the value of this hidden input whenever the user changes the tab:

```js
$('a[data-toggle="pill"]').on('shown.bs.tab', (e) => {
  $('#activetab').val(e.target.href.replace(/^#/, ''));
})
```

For example, if the user clicks on Tab 1, this will set the value of the input to `"evidence-form-1"`. Then, when the user submits the form, the browser will send the value of the hidden input to the server as `activetab=evidence-form-1`, which can be read from Django.

Note that the input won't have a value until the user switches tabs at least once. This may become a problem if the user does not click on any tabs before submitting the form. I'll leave it to you to figure out how to handle this scenario.